# цикл for:invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for, syntax

Hе могу запустить цикл `for`, хотя цикл `while` хорошо запускает. Выдаёт ошибку `invalid syntax` и всё. Выделяет двоеточие в конце строки с `for`.

Kод:

```
name = input("Как Вас зовут? ") #Берёт значение от пользователя
print ("Привет,", name) #Выводит значение заданное пользователем

#INT - число; FLOAT - число с точкой; STR - строка
number_1 = int(input("Ваше первое число: ")) #Указываем INT для того, чтобы выводилась не строка а число
number_2 = int(input("Ваше второе число: "))
r = number_1 + number_2 #Указываем переменной, что нужно сложить две других переменных

for res:
#Так же можно было указать перед в переменной RES, и преобразовать все переменные в ней как числа
if res >= 50: #Если переменная RES больше или равна 50
    if res >= 75: #Если больше 75
        print("Ваше число получилось какое-то большое, меняем... Теперь оно равно", res)
        res /= 2
        continue
    else: #Иначе
        print("Ещё бы чуть-чуть поменьше... Но мы изменим Ваш результат, теперь Ваше число равняется", res)
        res /= 2
        continue
elif res < 0: #Если RES меньше 0
    print("Не надо таких чисел. Прибавляем!")
    res += 100
    continue
else: #Иначе срабатывают все оставшиеся сценарии
    print("Вы ввели больше 0, но меньше 50. Вы молодец! Ваше число равняется", res)
    print("\nСтолько Вам полагается поцелуев!")

while res >= 75: #Цикл WHILE означает "Пока" не достигнет этого условия
    res /= 2 #Понижаем эту переменную, чтобы закончить цикл
    print ("Вы вводите слишком много. Умерьте свой аппетит. Впрочем... Мы сделали всё за Вас и уменьшаем его до нужного размера. Ваш результат теперь равняется", res)
    print ("Столько Вам полагается поцелуев!")
```

Comment: Судя по коду вы вообще не понимаете что такое цикл for...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica , а в каком направлении двигаться? я понимаю, что нужно что-то указать в for, но не понимаю что.

Comment: Железная логика. Надо знать что вам надо получить,  а не указать.

Comment: Цикл for работает так:`for <something> in <something_iteriable:list,range_etc.>: <do_something>`.Тем временем `<something>` принимает по порядку все значения из `<something_iteriable>` и вы можете юзать это в коде.

Comment: Ха-ха, вы думали, что заменив в коде while на for, сделаете из одного другое? 

Comment: @Эникейщик я надеялся на это. Как никак учусь и тут проблемка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могли бы вы объяснить что ваша программа должна делать?

Просто цикл for используется для проверки определенного диапазона чисел, букв в слове, слов, объектов в массивах, кортежах, словарях и т.д.

Т.е. в отличии от while он не может повторятся бесконечно.

Примеры :

1. Для проверки чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 100.

   ```
   for i in range(0, 101) : # указываем 101 т.к. range не учитывает последнее значение
      if i%2 == 0 : #делится на 2 без остатка, то есть четное ли оно
      print(i)
   ```

Примечание : переменная i  существует только в пределах цикла, то есть нигде в программе, кроме как в этом цикле, вы к ней обратиться не сможете. Это же дает нам возможность использовать ее в других циклах for

2. Если вам нужно  проверить какое-то число, записанное в переменную :

   ```
   variable = 100
   for i in range (0, variable + 1) :#опять же не забываем что последнее значение не учитывается. Также если надо проверить допустим от 0 до  100, а от 10 , то указываем range(10, 100) 
      if i % 3 == 0 : # делится ли оно  на 3 без остатка

       print(i)
   ```
3. Если вы проверяете слово :

   ```
   for i in 'qwerty' : #проверяет каждую букву, можно указать переменную
      if i == 'q' :
        print(i) #выведет букву q, если цикл сейчас на ней
   ```
4. Списки, кортежи, массивы - неважно :

   ```
     q = ['q', 'w', 1]
     for i in q :
         if i == 'q' :
             print(i)
   ```
5. Если вам нужно проверить какие-то определенные числа, каждое второе например.

   ```
      w = 100
      for i in range(0, w + 1) [::2] : #если я не ошибаюсь, это называется срез. Данная конструкция([начало : конец : шаг ]) также определяет диапазон и шаг. Отсчет начнется с числа которое указано в 'начале'. 
           print(i) : #выводит все четные числа (0, 2, 4, ..., 100). Если указать in range(0, w)[::2], то последним числом будет 98
   ```

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Я хотел бы, что бы она складывала два введённых числа, и по циклу приходила к одному ответу. Всё.

Comment: В вашем случае, пожалуй, я бы все же использовал  while.

Comment: спасибо за раскрытый ответ. Получается, чтобы добиться всё таки циклом for решения этой задачи, мне следует для каждого из трёх условия написать свой цикл? Или я не правильно понял?

Comment: Да, можно будет как-либо использовать цикл while, но из-за этого придется писать слишком большой код. Поэтому я все-таки останусь при своем мнении и порекомендую вам найти другой способ решения этой задачи. А если вы тем самым пытаетесь научиться использовать цикл for, то порекомендую просто найти задачи на данную тему в интернете, благо их очень много. и не только к языку python

Comment: да спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Я просто нашёл на Ютубе [плейлист с уроками для начинающих](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXgfuxOEDTCwsWmKezOaDTu) и решил не повторять за ним, а по урокам добавлять в код знания из предыдущих уроков. В итоге столкнулся с проблемой.

Comment: "Примечание : переменная i существует только в пределах цикла, то есть нигде в программе, кроме как в этом цикле, вы к ней обратиться не сможете." - переменная продолжает существовать после цикла, вы можете в сами в этом убедиться.

Comment: Да извините. Это моя ошибка. Просто когда я изучал это, нигде данный факт не упоминался.